# SSMA: Migration fails MySQL -> Azure SQL with no error

Tags: mysql, sql, azure, database-migration, azure-sql-database

I am getting this error when I attempt to migrate from `MySQL localhost DB to Azure SQL using MMSA` (SQL Server Migration Assistant) for MySQL

[image: ssma migration fail]

I have seen this around https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b835f4b3-3d93-42a4-9b6b-d21d3dfd8dab/ssma-error-migrate-data-mysql-sql-server?forum=sqlservermigration

Some suggestions are change MySQL connection from ANSI to unicode, make sure all db names are lowercase. Both do not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the bit of error message as text to the question to make it searchable. It would be nice whether you add links to the questions that did not help.

Comment: This looks like a product defect. Please open a support case: 
•Assisted support - Go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/assistedsupportproducts and search for ‘SQL Server Migration Assistant’. Select your version, then select “start request”. Assisted support is included with the SQL Server Migration Assistant Tool.